# How implant Facets with elasticsearch on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5, facet

I need to do facets for my app. For the moment, I want facets appear on the result page after search. I new on rails and sorry for my bad english, i m french.

I have 2 models : Camping.rb and Caracteristiquetest.rb. I made association has_many / belongs_to. In caracteristiquetest, I have one column camping_id and other string columns "piscine" and "barbecue".

So, after lot of tests, I found a solution to find a post with value "non" on caracteristiquetest.barbecue (see after). Now i try to implant this on app.

I have an error :

> C:/Sites/campsite/app/models/camping.rb:66: syntax error, unexpected
>   ':', expecting => {caracteristiquetest.barbecue : "non"}}] ^
>   C:/Sites/campsite/app/models/camping.rb:66: syntax error, unexpected
>   '}', expecting keyword_end {caracteristiquetest.barbecue : "non"}}] ^
>   C:/Sites/campsite/app/models/camping.rb:85: syntax error, unexpected
>   end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

How can do to fix it ?
By the way, after fixing that how i can implant this on my wiew ? I want to implant this function  after search to allow user to filter "barbecue" "yes" / "no".

Thanks for your help.

**_search with head_plugin elasticsearch**
When i run this i have the good result

```
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {"term": 
        {"caracteristiquetest.barbecue": "non"}}]
  }
 }
}
```

**campings_controller.rb**

```
  def homesearch
      @campings = Camping.custom_search((params[:q].present? ? params[:q] : '*'))
  end

#Page de résultats
  def result
    if params[:q].blank?
      redirect_to action: :index and return
    else
    @campings = Camping.custom_search((params[:q].present? ? params[:q] : '*')).page(params[:page]).per(14).results
    end

    end
```

**camping.rb**

```
   mapping do
   indexes :name, boost: 8
   indexes :adresse
   indexes :commune, boost: 10
   indexes :description
   indexes :nomdep, boost: 10
   indexes :nomregion, boost: 10
   indexes :ville_id
   indexes :region_id
   indexes :departement_id
   indexes :latitude
   indexes :longitude
   indexes :etoile
   indexes :user_id
   indexes :caracteristiquetest_id
   #On implante les données du modèle supplémentaire
    indexes :caracteristiquetests, type: 'nested' do
      indexes :id,   type: 'integer'
      indexes :piscine, type: 'string'
      indexes :barbecue, type: 'string'
      indexes :camping_id, type: 'integer'
    end
end

  def as_indexed_json(options = {})
    self.as_json(only: [:name, :adresse, :code_postale, :commune, :description, :nomdep, :nomregion, :latitude, :longitude, :etoile, :caracteristiquetest_id],
    include: {caracteristiquetest: {only: [:id, :piscine, :barbecue, :camping_id]}})
  end

  class << self
    def custom_search(query)
      __elasticsearch__.search(query: multi_match_query(query),  aggs: aggregations)
    end

    def multi_match_query(query)
      {
        multi_match: {
          query: query,
          type: "best_fields", 
          fields: ["name^6", "nomdep^10", "commune^8", "nomregion^7"],
          operator: "and"
        }
      }
    end
def aggregations
  {
query: {
  bool: {
    must: [
      {term:
        {caracteristiquetest.barbecue : "non"}}]
  }
 }
}
    end
  end
```

**homesearch.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="search">
                   <%= form_tag(result_path, method: :get) %>
                        <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q], class:"search-query form-control" %>
                  <%= submit_tag "GO", class:"btn btn-danger", name: nil %>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are trying to call `.facets` on something which is `nil`. In your case, `@camping` is `nil`. This is probably because you never set it in the controller action which is rendering the `result.html.erb` template. I see that you set `@camping` in the `index` action but not in the `result` action.

Comment: @CarlosRamirezIII You re right, it's a mistake i forget the "s" to @camping. I edited the post. Now i have another error undefined method `facets' for #<Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Results:0x130b3d38>

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to interact with the `results` interface of the response returned by Elasticsearch. Try interacting directly with the `response` object, e.g.

```
# don't call `.results` here because you want the full response object
@campings = Camping.__elasticsearch__.search(...)
```

As per the documentation

> The returned response object is a rich wrapper around the JSON
>   returned from Elasticsearch, providing access to response metadata and
>   the actual results ("hits").

Source: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-model/#Search_results

You should be able to figure out how to fetch the facets and any other data you need by inspecting the resulting JSON and reading the Elasticsearch documentation itself.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html

Comment: Thanks for this reply @Carlos I remove .results in @campings = Camping.elasticsearch... I always have an error "undefined method `facets' for #<Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Response:0x10488c18>" JSON is the problem ? What can i do ? sorry for noob questions...

Comment: You are calling `.facets` but that may not be the method name that you need. My suggestion would be to inspect the `@campings` variable and see what methods it has defined on it. Since it is just a wrapper around an Elasticsearch JSON response, the Elasticsearch documentation itself should be helpful in figuring out how to access the facets from the response. Please give the documentation a read and see how the response object is structured and where the facets are located.

Comment: Ok i will do that, i ll be back. For sure elasticsearch is not esy for the beginer :) Just one thing : how can inspect it ?

Comment: Agreed :) Hopefully that points you in the right direction and you are able to get it. LMK how it turns out.

Comment: Just one thing before : how can inspect it ? In head_plugin ?

Comment: Try using a Rails console session so you can interact with the response object. Type `rails console` to start a new session, then just run an Elasticsearch right there. `response = Camping.__elasticsearch__.search(...)`. Then you can `response.inspect` and try out different methods and see what's returned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122139/discussion-between-nicolaswecandoit-and-carlos-ramirez-iii).

Comment: After some tests, i find something but i have an another error, can u help please ? Thanks :)